How to set react-window height of list to be the height of the actual list, yet still virtualized?
Right now I have a "box" with an explicit height, on these unicode glyphs (200k+ rows), using react-window virtual scrolling (vertical):

How can I remove the need for the explicitly sized box, and have the white content area be the height of the virtualized list, yet the list is still virtualized? This way, the page still scrolls like you would normally expect, it's just that with this gigantic list, only the things within the browser viewport are visible? Is it possible with react-window?
I am basically just doing this:
import { VariableSizeList as List } from 'react-window'

<div className="w-full">
  <List
    className="w-full"
    height={containerHeight}
    itemCount={rows.length}
    itemSize={getItemSize}
    width={containerWidth}
  >
    {({ index, style }) => (
      <ListItem
        style={style}
        index={index}
      />
    )}
  </List>
</div>

